# MongoDB aggregation too slow after migration from 2.4 to 2.6.11

Tags: mongodb

In 2.4 version the aggregation works in about 1 minute and after migration to 2.6.11, the aggregation process ends in about 3 hours. I've recreated all indices but still remains slow. There are 6549937 objects in this collection.

The aggregation script:

```
db.runCommand({
aggregate: "Profile",
pipeline:
[
    { $match : { "count" : { "$gt" : 0} } },
    { $group : 
        { "_id" : "$type", "sum" : { "$sum" : "$count"}, 
        "count" : { "$sum" : 1}, "min" : { "$min" : "$count"} , 
        "max" : { "$max" : "$count"}
        }           
    },
    { $project:
        { _id: 1,
          count: 1,
          sum: 1,
          min: 1,
          max: 1
        }
    }
]});
```

Explain:

```
{
"stages" : [ 
    {
        "$cursor" : {
            "query" : {
                "count" : {
                    "$gt" : 0
                }
            },
            "fields" : {
                "count" : 1,
                "type" : 1,
                "_id" : 0
            },
            "plan" : {
                "cursor" : "BtreeCursor count_1",
                "isMultiKey" : false,
                "scanAndOrder" : false,
                "indexBounds" : {
                    "count" : [ 
                        [ 
                            0, 
                            Infinity
                        ]
                    ]
                },
                "allPlans" : [ 
                    {
                        "cursor" : "BtreeCursor count_1",
                        "isMultiKey" : false,
                        "scanAndOrder" : false,
                        "indexBounds" : {
                            "count" : [ 
                                [ 
                                    0, 
                                    Infinity
                                ]
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }, 
    {
        "$group" : {
            "_id" : "$type",
            "sum" : {
                "$sum" : "$count"
            },
            "count" : {
                "$sum" : {
                    "$const" : 1
                }
            },
            "min" : {
                "$min" : "$count"
            },
            "max" : {
                "$max" : "$count"
            }
        }
    }, 
    {
        "$project" : {
            "_id" : true,
            "count" : true,
            "sum" : true,
            "min" : true,
            "max" : true
        }
    }
],
"ok" : 1 }
```

Explain query in 2.4 version:

```
{
"cursor" : "BtreeCursor count_1",
"isMultiKey" : false,
"n" : 5710623,
"nscannedObjects" : 5710623,
"nscanned" : 5710623,
"nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 5710623,
"nscannedAllPlans" : 5710623,
"scanAndOrder" : false,
"indexOnly" : false,
"nYields" : 36445,
"nChunkSkips" : 0,
"millis" : 3556300,
"indexBounds" : {
    "count" : [ 
        [ 
            0, 
            1.797693134862316e+308
        ]
    ]
},
"allPlans" : [ 
    {
        "cursor" : "BtreeCursor count_1",
        "n" : 5710623,
        "nscannedObjects" : 5710623,
        "nscanned" : 5710623,
        "indexBounds" : {
            "count" : [ 
                [ 
                    0, 
                    1.797693134862316e+308
                ]
            ]
        }
    }
],
"oldPlan" : {
    "cursor" : "BtreeCursor count_1",
    "indexBounds" : {
        "count" : [ 
            [ 
                0, 
                1.797693134862316e+308
            ]
        ]
    }
}}
```

Explain query in 2.6.11 version

```
{
"cursor" : "BtreeCursor count_1",
"isMultiKey" : false,
"n" : 5710623,
"nscannedObjects" : 5710623,
"nscanned" : 5710623,
"nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 5710623,
"nscannedAllPlans" : 5710623,
"scanAndOrder" : false,
"indexOnly" : false,
"nYields" : 2585642,
"nChunkSkips" : 0,
"millis" : 17121523,
"indexBounds" : {
    "count" : [ 
        [ 
            0, 
            Infinity
        ]
    ]
},
"allPlans" : [ 
    {
        "cursor" : "BtreeCursor count_1",
        "isMultiKey" : false,
        "n" : 5710623,
        "nscannedObjects" : 5710623,
        "nscanned" : 5710623,
        "scanAndOrder" : false,
        "indexOnly" : false,
        "nChunkSkips" : 0,
        "indexBounds" : {
            "count" : [ 
                [ 
                    0, 
                    Infinity
                ]
            ]
        }
    }
],
"filterSet" : false,
"stats" : {
    "type" : "FETCH",
    "works" : 8293430,
    "yields" : 2585642,
    "unyields" : 2585642,
    "invalidates" : 2583,
    "advanced" : 5710623,
    "needTime" : 0,
    "needFetch" : 2580241,
    "isEOF" : 1,
    "alreadyHasObj" : 0,
    "forcedFetches" : 0,
    "matchTested" : 0,
    "children" : [ 
        {
            "type" : "IXSCAN",
            "works" : 5710623,
            "yields" : 2585642,
            "unyields" : 2585642,
            "invalidates" : 2583,
            "advanced" : 5710623,
            "needTime" : 0,
            "needFetch" : 0,
            "isEOF" : 1,
            "keyPattern" : "{ count: 1 }",
            "isMultiKey" : 0,
            "boundsVerbose" : "field #0['count']: (0.0, inf.0]",
            "yieldMovedCursor" : 0,
            "dupsTested" : 0,
            "dupsDropped" : 0,
            "seenInvalidated" : 0,
            "matchTested" : 0,
            "keysExamined" : 5710623,
            "children" : []
        }
    ]
}}
```

Comment: Can you run an explain passing in true please. `db.collection.query().explain(true)` and post result

Comment: also have you tried version 3?

Comment: Not that it solely resolves the time difference ( or should not ), but that trailing `$project` is not doing anything other than adding another pass through the result data. It would appear that someone was trying to order the keys that are output, but that does not work that way in an aggregation pipeline, and the contents will just be emitted in the same order as they are specified in the `$group` stage. I can note that there was a discrepency with index key exclusions between 2.4 and 2.6, that I think might be resolved in 3.2.

Comment: And I believe @Hughzi was trying to say `db.Profile.find({ "count": { "$gt": 0 } }).explain(true)`. And actually from both versions 2.4 and 2.6 if possible, where I believe there would be a difference in `nScanned` statistics.

Comment: Thread was update with requested informations